# Total size of array must be unchanged

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, distribution, emcee

I am using a Python module called emcee to sample a distribution. I need to pass a (37,100) (which I have named Ntrig and Nsamp, respectively) array called `events` to the below function.

```
def mp(SNR2, *events):
    events = np.asarray(events).reshape((Ntrig,Nsamp))
    bessel = special.iv(0,np.sqrt(x*SNR2(event)))
    exp = np.exp(-0.5*(x+SNR2(event)))
    I = integrate.quad(lambda x: exp*bessel,0,SNRth**2)[0]
    return np.asarray([np.array[I for event in events[i]] for i in range(len(events))]).reshape(events.shape)
```

I keep getting the error:

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

As I understand, `*events` will break up the `events` array into 37*100 separate arguments. Shouldn't the next line where I reshape the array just put it back into a 37 by 100 array?

P.S. before you ask why I even bother breaking up `events` into separate arguments--the module needs this to work, it can't take an array.

Full Traceback error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-c8e815326a69> in <module>()
----> 1 mp(SNR2,events)

<ipython-input-16-9f73f234c628> in mp(SNR2, *events)
      5 def mp(SNR2, *events):
      6     events = np.asarray(events).reshape((Ntrig,Nsamp))
----> 7     return np.asarray([np.array([integrate.quad(lambda x: np.exp(-0.5*(x+SNR2(event)))*special.iv(0,np.sqrt(x*SNR2(event))),0,SNRth**2)[0] for event in events[i]]) for i in range(len(events))]).reshape(events.shape)
      8 #    return integrate.quad(lambda x: 0.5*np.exp(-0.5*(x+SNR2(event)))*special.iv(0,np.sqrt(x*SNR2(event))),0,SNRth**2)[0]
      9 def pp(SNR2, *events):

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    279         args = (args,)
    280     if (weight is None):
--> 281         retval = _quad(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit,points)
    282     else:
    283         retval = _quad_weight(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limlst,limit,maxp1,weight,wvar,wopts)

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    343     if points is None:
    344         if infbounds == 0:
--> 345             return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    346         else:
    347             return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

<ipython-input-16-9f73f234c628> in <lambda>(x)
      5 def mp(SNR2, *events):
      6     events = np.asarray(events).reshape((Ntrig,Nsamp))
----> 7     return np.asarray([np.array([integrate.quad(lambda x: np.exp(-0.5*(x+SNR2(event)))*special.iv(0,np.sqrt(x*SNR2(event))),0,SNRth**2)[0] for event in events[i]]) for i in range(len(events))]).reshape(events.shape)
      8 #    return integrate.quad(lambda x: 0.5*np.exp(-0.5*(x+SNR2(event)))*special.iv(0,np.sqrt(x*SNR2(event))),0,SNRth**2)[0]
      9 def pp(SNR2, *events):

<ipython-input-16-9f73f234c628> in SNR2(*events)
      1 def SNR2(*events):
----> 2     events = np.asarray(events).reshape((Ntrig,Nsamp))
      3     C = 5*np.pi**(-1.33333)*events**(1.66667)/(96*d**2)
      4     return C*integrate.quad(lambda f: f**(-2.3333)/S(f), 20, 1500, limit=1000)[0]
      5 def mp(SNR2, *events):

ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As I understand, `events` will break up the events array into 37*100 separate arguments.

This is not true. If you call `mp` using

```
mp(SNR2, events)
```

then inside `mp`, `events` will be a 1-element tuple, `(arr,)`, where `arr` is the (37, 100)-shaped array.

If you call `mp` using

```
mp(SNR2, *events)
```

then inside `mp`, `events` will be a 37-element tuple, where the 37 elements are the 37 rows of the (37, 100)-shaped array.

If you call `mp` using

```
mp(SNR2, *events.flat)
```

then inside `mp`, `events` will be a tuple of 37*100 elements.

---

Notice that the last stanza of the traceback says:

```
<ipython-input-16-9f73f234c628> in SNR2(*events)
      1 def SNR2(*events):
----> 2     events = np.asarray(events).reshape((Ntrig,Nsamp))
      3     C = 5*np.pi**(-1.33333)*events**(1.66667)/(96*d**2)
      4     return C*integrate.quad(lambda f: f**(-2.3333)/S(f), 20, 1500, limit=1000)[0]
      5 def mp(SNR2, *events):

ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

So the error is raised while Python is in the `SNR2` function.

Since `SNR2` was called in `mp` using `SNR2(event)`, and `event` is a (37,100)-shaped array, the `event` variable in `SNR2` is a 1-element tuple containing the original array. That's not what you want.

The easiest way to fix the code is to define

```
def SNR2(events):  
    # no longer needed
    # events = np.asarray(events).reshape((Ntrig,Nsamp))
```

and just pass events around as one would expect.

However, if you can not change the signature of `SNR2`, then you must call it with

```
SNR2(*event.flat)
```

inside the `mp` function.

---

Reference: Here is [an excellent explanation](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) of the `*` unpacking operator, and how the syntax is used when defining functions, and calling functions.

Comment: Why am I getting the error `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged` and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you just asking "how do I force the array to break up into 37*100 separate elements"? If so, `*iter(events)` will do that, or `*list(events)`, or `*(events.reshape((37*100,))`, etc.

Comment: I don't know. On what line are you getting that error? Please post the full traceback error message.

Comment: I'm getting the error on the second line of the code, where I reshape `events`. `events` is already a (37,100) array. When I input it into the function, I need to use *events. I then want to reshape events back into a (37,100) array. When I try to do this, however, I get the aforementioned error.

Comment: I should mention: when I test this simple code:
`def func(*events):

    events = np.asarray(events).reshape((Ntrig,Nsamp))
    return events`
there is no problem.

Comment: @unutbu I editted the original post with the full traceback error.

Comment: That seems very odd -- maybe a contradiction. Since Python executes each statement line-by-line, if `mp` and `func` are identical up to the call to `reshape`, then one should not cause an Exception while the other does not.

Comment: @unutbu what do you mean by contradiction? And yes, it's odd, it's been really eating at me haha

Comment: Ohh.. The exception is raised in SNR2, not mp!

Comment: @unutbu but SNR2 runs perfectly! SNR2(events) outputs a (37,100) array